# Unhide new cells with openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to add a new sheet to an existing XLSX document with OpenPyxl and Python 2.7. Adding the cells works, but the cells are hidden, actually the whole column.

This the code:

```
ws = wb.create_sheet(title='newsheet')


for i in range(0, len(items)-1):
  c = ws.cell(column=1, row=i+1)
  c.value = 'foo'
  c.style.protection = Protection(hidden=False)

wb.save('new_file.xlsx')
```

I don't see 'foo' in the resulting spreadsheet.

Comment: Can you add a little more context? If I try the code you posted, but put in my own preexisting workbook and make up my own `items`, I get a traceback with `AttributeError: 'Cell' object has no attribute 'hidden'`. (Also, you don't need trailing semicolons in Python.)

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by "hidden"? Do you mean the column is hidden (effectively, width zero) and you don't want it hidden? Or do you mean the cells have nonzero height and width, but their contents are not visible? Or are you referring to something to do with protection?

Comment: hmm... it could be that the width of the new column is zero and therefore the cells are hidden. i'll check that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Excel ignores row or column styles for existing cells so you have to apply them to individual cells. As a result, openpyxl only interprets styles applied to individual cells as relevant to those cells. See http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/2.3.0-b1/styles.html#applying-styles for further information.

Comment: ok, thanks, but the basic approach above is correct? i removed the column dimensions hidden statement, still the new cells are hidden....

Comment: As I said, Excel ignores column dimensions for existing cells so it doesn't make much sense to change the hidden value for the column. You have to do it cell by cell. Sorry, but that's the way the file format works.

Comment: XlsxWriter handles row and column styles just fine. Any cell in the affected row or column that is not otherwise styled picks up the row or column style.